# node.js format scientific notation in json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I am working with a JSON file that includes numbers formatted in scientific notation with a fixed number of decimals, like this:

```
{"value": 2.421500000000000e+04 }
```

My node.js application reads this JSON file, changes some of the values and rewrites the file. The file is later to be used by a different application that expects this specific JSON format.

This numeric value in scientific notation can be easily read as number by parsing the JSON but I have not been able to write it. If written as a number, scientific notation and fixed decimals are not preserved. If formatted in scientific notation, the value is written as a string and double-quoted. I would like to either:

- Save as a number formatted in scientific notation with fixed decimals
- Save as a string without quotes

Is there a way to do any of this?

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935358/nodejs-json-parse-preserve-scientific-notation/44935725) asking more or less the same but it actually has no answer if the format cannot be changed. What I want to achieve is not to maintain the format of the parsed number but to be able to write a number in the format above.

Comment: Even with using a `replacer` with `JSON.stringify()`, there appears to be no way to achieve this - as soon as I return a string value from the replacer, it gets wrapped into double quotes. (Makes sense, it can't be the job of the algorithm to check if the value _might_ be a number at this point.) I am guessing that you probably have little other choice here, than to insert the scientific notation _as_ a string, and then do a search&replace to remove the double quotes around these values ... (or, write a complete custom JSON "stringifier" yourself.)

Comment: _"The file is later to be used by a different application that expects this specific JSON format."_ - [speaking-to-dog voice] Bad Application! (I hope it at least doesn't pretend to "speak JSON" then, if it enforces such arbitrary restrictions.)

Comment: JSON parser seems to present numbers in science format when exponent is larger than 20 or smaller than -6, trailing zeroes will be lost in all cases. In a word, the application doesn't expect data being JSON, it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

> expects this specific JSON format

Seems a strange requirement by the other application.

But doing what @CBroe kind of mentioned, you could use the replacer in the stringify method, and using some `magic` tag, you could then trim out the unwanted `"`..

eg.

```js
var obj = {"value": 2.421500000000000e+04 };

const magic = '||';

function expNum(n) {
  const k = n.toExponential().split('e');
  const k2 = k[1].split('+');
  return `${magic}${k[0].padEnd(17, '0')}e+${k2[1].padStart(2,'0')}${magic}`;
}

function showIt() {
  const output = JSON.stringify(obj, 
    (key, value) => {
      if (typeof value === 'number') 
        return expNum(value)
      else return value
  }, '  ')
    .replaceAll(`"${magic}`,'')
    .replaceAll(`${magic}"`,'');
  console.log(output);
}

showIt();
console.log('multiply by 700000');
obj.value *= 700000;
showIt();
```