# NodeJS - dealing with float numbers with zero after the point

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

NodeJS treats float values with a zero after the point as integer!
This is on the language level.
**For example: 5.0 is treated as 5.**

I am working with APIs and I must be able to send float values with zero after the point and to be able to accept this in my server exactly as it was sent.

For example, I have this simple endpoint:

```
app.post('/float-hell', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.json({ x: req.body.x });
});
```

When I send `{"x":6.2}` it is indeed accepted as `6.2`.
But if I send it as `{"x":5.0}` it is accepted as `5`.

APIs should be able to accept such a value because they must be language-agnostic and should allow any language to work with them.

Please help me overcome this limitation. I tried everything that came to mind, I tried doing manipulations with `parseFloat()` - nothing works.

I did everything that came to mind, it seems like a language limitation

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Numbers are numbers. What you are seeing are the conventions of how numbers are converted to strings for display.

Comment: Also note that `5` and `5.0` are precisely the same value anyway.

Comment: `I must be able to send float values with zero after the point `   That sounds a problem with the API your sending too.  But if you must send JSON in a strange format, this link did something similar -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76262315/node-js-format-scientific-notation-in-json-file/76262511#76262511

Comment: If this is a real issue then it sounds like a problem with the API back end.  JSON doesn't itself have a distinction between floats and integers, and the format is based on JavaScript's double-precision floats, so any system using the JSON number data format which cares about such things is not behaving reasonably.  (If it really cares about representation it should use a string.)  You could completely wrap or reimplement `JSON.stringify()` if you want, but this feels like a major XY problem, where X is "the API is bad".

Comment: To put these arguments another way, what do you expect the value of `5 - 5.0` to be?

Comment: If you can send the value as a string, you could send the value in any format you want.

Comment: Like, you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5xA5w), does that address the question fully?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value as a string and then parse it

```
app.post('/float-hell', async (req, res) => {
  const x = req.body.x.toString(); // Convert the value to a string
  res.json({ x: x });
});
```

Comment: So that will just become -> `{"x": "5"}` .  The OP is after `{"x": 5.0}`